# Using public Amazon Machine Image

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2

I am using Amazon EC2 service in my application, to create an instance of AMI I have to pass 'RunInstancesRequest' as parameter for this I need Access Key,AMI Id, Secret Access Key, Security Group etc..but I dnt have any AMI any Idea howw can I create an Instance of any Public AMI, I need to test my Application

Will really appreciate for any help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

install elastic fox plugin in firefox. There are lot of public AMIs available. You can look at the list of public AMIs in elastic fox plugin in the AMIs tab. Secret access key can be found in your amazon account settings.

Comment: Thanks buddy I installed Elastic fox plugin but not sure where to look for AMIs tab??

Comment: You have to filter the list according to which AMI you want. For instance, I often use AMIs with Ubuntu Linux pre-installed, so I'd type 'ubuntu' into Elastic Fox.

Comment: @TiM but Elastic Fox is not showing any EMI :(, do you I require to configure something??

Comment: I had to give Elastic Fox my Amazon credentials first. But after that, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know what operating system and/or software you wanted to see installed on your AMI. However, to get you started, here's some Ubuntu AMIs: http://alestic.com/

An old Ubuntu AMI I've been using: ami-ccf615a5

Comment: Tim I dnt have Amazon Ec2 accout because it looks it is payable..and I want to test my application any Isea how can I do this???

Comment: I'm afraid you need to sign up to Amazon EC2 in order to test against it. You only pay for what you use, though, so it needn't be expensive.

Comment: hmmm thanks for the support Tim I thought there must be some way to test application....